# how to get primitive type from object in Java?

Tags: java

Let x be a given object of primitive type, e.g. x is defined by  `int x;` or `char x;` or ....etc.

Then, how to get name of class (i.e., `int` or `char` or ...etc) from `x`?

**Motivation:**

```
if(primitive type of x = int) then ....
if(primitive type of x = char) then ....
```

Comment: In this case you are talking about primitives, not classes. There is no need to find out what `x` is, because if you defined it as `int x` it can only be an int. It cannot change.

Comment: I want to get some function which returns `int` or `char` ...etc.

Comment: `String getType(int x) { return "int"; }`

Comment: That does not exist in java. The question is: can you come up with a scenario where you don't know what type a variable is (assuming it's a primitive)?

Comment: I assume that I do not know `x` is `int` or `char` or....

Comment: Your edited answer suggests this might be an XY problem.  What are you doing where you would need this capability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing are primitive types, not classes. You can do it like this.

```
class Foo {
    public int x;
    public char y;
}

Foo foo = new Foo();
Field[] fields = foo.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
for (Field f : fields) {
    System.out.println(f.getAnnotatedType() + " " + f.getName());
}
```

prints

```
int x
char y
```

If you just want to have a getter to return a value of a primitive field you can do this in your class.

```
int someVal = 10;
public int getSomeVal() {
    return someVal;
}
```

Comment: This only works for class fields though, not for something like local variables.

Comment: @f1sh  Good point.

Answer (score -1):

This should help you get started for Java classes.

```
public int x

 class DoSomething (int x) { 
    ...
    }
```

Some relevant links:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html

Comment: What is the point of this answer? How does it help?